# Refused to load the stylesheet (meta tags dont work)

Tags: html, css, vue.js, frontend, material-design

On the deployed version of my site I can't see any icons (from material design icons) that I got by using a style sheet like so

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@latest/css/materialdesignicons.css">
```

I get the error

```
Refused to load the stylesheet 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@latest/css/materialdesignicons.css' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com/ 'unsafe-inline'". Note that 'style-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'style-src' is used as a fallback.
```

[Error that occured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrSKg.png)

I have tried using the meta tags, but failed

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com/ 'unsafe-inline';">
```

If anybody has a clue how to solve this error I would be eternally gratefull

Comment: seems CSP issue . [https://content-security-policy.com/](https://content-security-policy.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your CSP does not include `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net` in the `style-src` section. Your updated CSP could look like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com https://cdn.jsdelivr.net 'unsafe-inline';">
```

As a side note: Using the value `'unsafe-inline'` should, as the name implies, only be used if you know what you are doing. One could say that inline JS is "more dangerous" than inline CSS, but still - if you don't need this value, then just remove it. See [CSP style-src: 'unsafe-inline' - is it worth it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30653698/csp-style-src-unsafe-inline-is-it-worth-it) Of course, if you are using a framework like Angular, then it might be necessary to enable this. However, IMHO it is important to keep the meanings/implications of the individual tags in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use an import in the stylesheet or in  tags:

```
    @import url('https://YourFontLink');
```

If this doesn't work, you have a problem with your link, the roboto font link for CSS is [here](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto), just select @import radio button